# Python phonenumbers module's region_code_for_number not working for few numbers

Tags: python

I have been using phonenumbers module to determine the country from a given phone number. This has been working fine for most of the numbers, however I recently noticed that it is not able to determine the country code for a UK number. Example is given below:-

**Working:-**

+441212306868

region_code_for_number(phonenumbers.parse('+441212306868'))

'GB'

**Not working:-**

+441781894985

region_code_for_number(phonenumbers.parse('+441781894985'))

NO OUTPUT

Does anybody know why there is no output for this number even if country code and number length is same? Does STD code matters here?

Regards,
Aditya

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UK telephone numbers have area codes. You can view the list of valid area codes on the ofcom website https://www.ofcom.org.uk/phones-telecoms-and-internet/advice-for-consumers/advice/telephone-area-codes-tool

01781 is not a valid uk area code. If you are dialling international format then you would replace the 0 with +44

```
01779   Peterhead
01780   Stamford
01782   Stoke-on-Trent
01784   Staines
```